# How to make generic component with form control input for Angular Forms in app

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, ng-bootstrap, angular-forms

I've created component for datepicker that I want to use in many other components in my application. I have some problems becouse it doesn't change value of parent form group control.

Lets get to the code:

```
export class DatePickerComponent {
@ViewChild('input', {read: ElementRef, static: false}) inputRef: ElementRef;
@Input()
formName?: FormGroup;
@Input()
formControlName: any;

constructor() {
this.formControlName.setValue(['']);
}

onKeyPress = (event) => {
const pressedKey = event.keyCode;

if (
  pressedKey !== 8 &&
  pressedKey !== 9 &&
  pressedKey !== 13 &&
  ((pressedKey < 48 || pressedKey > 105) || (pressedKey > 57 && pressedKey < 96))
) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
}

onKeyUp = (event) => {
const pressedKey = event.keyCode;
const inputString: string = this.formControlName.value;

if (!inputString) {
  return;
}

if (inputString.length === 11) {
  this.inputRef.nativeElement.value = inputString.slice(0, -1);
  return;
}

if (pressedKey === 8 && (inputString.length === 3 || inputString.length === 6)) {
  const newValue = inputString.slice(0, -1);
  this.formControlName.setValue(newValue);
  this.inputRef.nativeElement.value = newValue;
} else if (inputString.length === 2 || inputString.length === 5) {
  const newValue = inputString + '/';
  this.formControlName.setValue(newValue);
  this.inputRef.nativeElement.value = newValue;
}
}

}
```

And the template:

```
<div [formGroup]="formName">
<input
class="form-control"
formControlName="{{formControlName}}"
placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
name="dp"
ngbDatepicker
#d="ngbDatepicker"
[minDate]="{year: 1930, month: 1, day: 1}"
(click)="d.toggle()"
(keydown)="onKeyPress($event)"
(keyup)="onKeyUp($event)">
</div>
```

So I wanted to use it in parent component that is form with `FormGroup` property set to X. To use my component I've added 
`<app-date-picker [formControlName]="birthDate" [formName]="registerForm"></app-date-picker>`

Maybe I did something wrong in parent component:

```
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() isRegisterPage: boolean;
@Input() isProfilePage: boolean;
@Input() user: UserInfo;
registerForm: FormGroup;
birthDate: FormControl;
loading: boolean;
.e
.t
.c
```

How to make my datepicker reusable correctly? Maybe somone can help me?

Fiddle with only datepicker (not used in parent form): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i47zuz-jj5glk?file=app/datepicker-popup.ts

Answer (score 1):

you are doing it wrong !, to make your custom component work with forms as `FormControl` you should make it `FormControl`, to do so, you need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` interface, so your component would work as custom `FormControl`, you can read how to do it here -> [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor), if you have problems on implementing it let me know, I can provide further help, but try to implement it on your own first, to learn better

Comment: Hi @Artyom, thanks for Your answer. I tried to implement ControlValueAccessor interface but it's not so easy for me. What I did is in the fiddle: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i47zuz . I have two imporant method (onKeyPress and onKeyUp - I need them to put `/` after 2 and 4 digits to make date format as expected and there I'm setting value of form control name. Could You help me with this?

Comment: @DominikZ here I wrote minimal implementation https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i47zuz-gwsvav, you can check it and implement on it your version, also check comments I wrote, it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Really you need't make a custom form Control, it's only pass the control as input

In parent, e.g.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <my-component [control]="form.get('bithdate')"></my-component>
</form>
```

You component

```
<input [formControl]="control" ...>

@Input() control:FormControl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at a library I wrote for building forms called Easy Angular. https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez it allows you to build self validating forms with very little code and extending the controls to make your own is easy.

Here is a BootStrap date picker implemented in it.

```
import { Component, Optional, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

import {
  EzControlBase,
  EzFormDirective,
  EzFormConfigService,
  EzFormConfigDirective,
  EzFormReadonlyDirective
} from 'ngx-ez';

@Component({
  selector: 'ez-date',
  templateUrl: './ez-date.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ez-date.component.css'],
  providers: [{ provide: EzControlBase, useExisting: EzDateComponent }]
})
export class EzDateComponent extends EzControlBase {
  constructor(
    configService: EzFormConfigService,
    @Optional() configDirective: EzFormConfigDirective,
    @Optional() ezForm: EzFormDirective,
    @Optional() ezezReadonly: EzFormReadonlyDirective,
    @Self() @Optional() ngControl: NgControl
  ) {
    super(configService, configDirective, ezForm, ezezReadonly, ngControl);
  }
}
```

and the template

```
<ez-control>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <ng-container controls-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="readonly$ | async">{{ value | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</ng-container>
    <input bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY' }" [id]="(name$ | async) + '_control_input'" [attr.aria-describedby]="(valid$ | async) ? null : (name$ | async) + '_validation_message'" [attr.maxlength]="maxlength$ | async" type="text" [attr.placeholder]="placeholder$ | async" [value]="value | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'" (bsValueChange)="onChange($event)"
      [ngClass]="(config$ | async).inputClasses" [valid]="valid$ | async" [class.d-none]="readonly$ | async">
  </ng-container>
</ez-control>
```

See a working demo at this StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1wshi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fez-date%2Fez-date.component.html