# Angular Generic Form dynamic dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement **dynamic forms** based on the example demonstrated in [How to make generic component with form control input for Angular Forms in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466582/how-to-make-generic-component-with-form-control-input-for-angular-forms-in-app).
However, how do I load an asynchronous list for a select control?
And how do I fill in a second select based on the first?

```
  async loadGender() {
    return of<any>([
        { value: "", label: "Bitte auswählen", selected: true },
        { value: "0", label: "männlich" },
        { value: "1", label: "weiblich" }
      ]).pipe(
      delay(2000)
    );
  }
    async loadStyle() {
    return of<any>([
        { value: "",  gender: '' , label: "X", selected: true },
        { value: "0", gender: '0',  label: "Y" },
        { value: "1", gender: '1',  label: "Z" }
      ]).pipe(
      delay(2000)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let first= this.loadGender().map(res => res.json());
let second= this.loadStyle().map(res => res.json());

Observable.forkJoin([first, second]).subscribe(results => {
  console.log('my new result',results)
});
```

This how to combine two observables

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26205971)

Comment: I apologize, when writing the question I ended up copying the wrong link. I am posting here the correct link to the generic reactive form.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-generic-form?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I can't edit the answer to change the wrong link. The correct link is this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-generic-form?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I presume, because of the link you referenced, you're using [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

You want to look at the [`valueChanges`](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#reactive-forms) observable, which emits a value each time our form control value changes.

By using the emitted value, we can fetch an updated list of options for our second `select` element.

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public carsForm: FormGroup;
  public cars$: Observable<any[]>;
  public models$: Observable<any[]>;

  private carFormControl = new FormControl("");
  private modelFormControl = new FormControl("");
  private carChangeSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.carsForm = this.fb.group({
      car: this.carFormControl,
      model: this.modelFormControl
    });

    this.cars$ = this.getCars();

    this.carChangeSubscription = this.carFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(
      carId => {
        this.modelFormControl.setValue("");
        this.models$ = this.getModels(+carId);
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.carChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  private getCars() {
    return of([
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "MERCEDES-BENZ"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "VOLVO"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "AUDI"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "HONDA"
      }
    ]);
  }

  private getModels(carId: number) {
    return of([
      {
        id: 1,
        carId: 1,
        name: "SL55 AMG"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        carId: 2,
        name: "C70"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        carId: 3,
        name: "S4"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        carId: 4,
        name: "CR-V"
      }
    ]).pipe(
      map(models => {
        return models.filter(x => x.carId === carId);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="carsForm">
   <select formControlName="car">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let car of cars$ | async" [value]="car.id">
      {{car.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <br /><br />
  <select formControlName="model">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let model of models$ | async" [value]="model.id">
      {{model.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

The [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) subscribes to our two data observables.

We [unsubscribe](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#cleaning-up-on-instance-destruction) from the `valueChanges` observable when the component is destroyed.